# Get data from channel 3 and send the least 8 bits to port B

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, avr

Get data from channel 3 and send the least 8 bits to port B.
Meanwhile transfer data from PINC to PORT D.

- Prescaling = 32
- Vref = 5V
- ADLAR = 1

This is a question that concerns ADC in AVR microcontrollers. I tried solving it, but I just couldn't understand how to send the least 8 bits to PORT B. I'm assuming the process is going to involve using some sort of shift or rotation instructions? I already got the ADMUX to be 0x63. ADCSRA is 0x85 before conversion starts and 0xC5 after conversion starts.

Can someone please help how can I do this?

Comment: Which exact MCU are you using? Your question is very unclear. Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: I can not imagine a use case where you want to only use the least 8 bit of an ADC result. Are you sure this is correct?

Answer (score 0):

`ADMUX=0x63` setup seems to be correct. You are reading data from channel `ADC3`. `ADCSRA` can be configured with two different modes. Data can be red with polling or interrupt, e.g.:

### Polling

```c
#include <avr/io.h>

int main(void)
{
  // Configure some port for output:
  DDRB = 0xFF;

  // Setup ADC
  // Channel 3
  // Left adjustment
  // 5V reference
  ADMUX = (1<<REFS0) | (1<<ADLAR) | (1<<MUX1) | (1<<MUX0);

  // Enable ADC with prescaler 32
  ADCSRA = (1<<ADEN) | (1<<ADPS2) | (1<<ADPS0);

  while(1)
  {
     // Start single conversion
     ADCSRA |= (1<<ADEN) | (1<<ADSC);
            
     // Wait until conversion is in progress
     while(ADCSRA & (1<<ADSC))
       asm volatile("NOP");
     
     // Not necessary you can only read ADCH
     unsigned char ADC_LOW = ADCL;   // Save ADC LOW value to variable
     unsigned char ADC_HIGH = ADCH;  // Save ADC HIGH value to variable
            
     // Return ADC high value (MSB10:LSB2) to a PORT
     PORTB = ADC_HIGH;
  }
}
```

### Interrupt controlled

```c
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

ISR(ADC_vect)
{
  PORTB = ADCH;
}

int main(void)
{
  // Configure some port for output:
  DDRB = 0xFF;

  // Setup ADC
  // Channel 3
  // Left adjustment
  // 5V reference
  ADMUX = (1<<REFS0) | (1<<ADLAR) | (1<<MUX1) | (1<<MUX0);

  // Enable ADC with prescaler 32
  ADCSRA = (1<<ADEN) | (1<<ADATE) | (1<<ADIE) | (1<<ADPS2) | (1<<ADPS0);

  // Enable interrupts globally
  sei();

  while(1)
  {
  }
}
```

Currently i have no plattform to test the code.